# JQuery $.ajaxSend() not working in Firefox(33.0)

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I have:

```
..............
$(document)
   .ajaxSend(function () {
   alert('test'); //for testing in FF
      switch (flag_mask) {
       case 0:
              mask_find_way.hide();
              mask_create_way.hide();
              mask_load.show();
              break;
       case 1:
              mask_load.hide();
              mask_create_way.hide();
              mask_find_way.show();
              break;
       case 2:
              mask_find_way.hide();
              mask_load.hide();
              mask_create_way.show();
              break;
 }
 }).ajaxStop(function () {
   mask_load.hide();
   mask_find_way.hide();
   mask_create_way.hide();
 });
..............
```

I trying with jquery 1.8.3, 1.11.1, 2.1.1 and $.ajaxSend() not working only in FF(alert not working too)?

Comment: The alert won't be shown until you actually make an ajax request with jQuery, have you done that?

Comment: Yes of couse, i trying in other browsers and not working only in FF.

Comment: *"alert not working too"* Say what now? I assure you `alert` works in Firefox.

Comment: Check the web console. Dollars to doughnuts you'll find an error there that's preventing your script run running and attaching the callback.

Comment: "$(document)
   .ajaxSend(function () {
   alert('test'); //for testing in FF})" this not working

Comment: This works fine in firefox 33 http://jsfiddle.net/m9j2ro41/

Comment: In web console no errors with jquery.

Comment: i dunno why not working my script....

Comment: That is the jQuery ready-wrapper function. If your ajax call needs to access the dom, you need to do it after the dom has finished loading. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: $.ready() is working fine in FF, but $.ajaxSend() not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working is fine:

```
  function preload_mask() {
     $(document)
        .ajaxSend(function () {
          switch (flag_mask) {
                case 0:
                       mask_find_way.hide();
                       mask_create_way.hide();
                       mask_load.show();
                       break;
                case 1:
                       mask_load.hide();
                       mask_create_way.hide();
                       mask_find_way.show();
                       break;
                case 2:
                       mask_find_way.hide();
                       mask_load.hide();
                       mask_create_way.show();
                       break;
          }
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
          mask_load.hide();
          mask_find_way.hide();
          mask_create_way.hide();
        });
  }
  $(window).load(function() {
      preload_mask();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//sometimes it works,sometimes it not.
$(document).ajaxSend(callback);

// will always work well.
$(function(){
   $(document).ajaxSend(callback);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.